# How to get Application server name using Jquery or javascript or typescrpit?

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have hosted the UI part separately and I want get application server name where UI part hosted and display it on screen.

So could you please help me to get application server name using server name using jQuery or JavaScript or typescript or any other alternative way without using server side code ?

Thanks in Advance

Regards

Manikandan

Comment: Hi mani, for security reason many hides their server details in the response. In that case, you won't able to find out any details. The best is to do this at serverside only

Comment: Can you explain your use case in more detail and be more explicit about what exactly it is you need?